# Take minimum dated record and count subsequent records in a specific timeframe

Tags: sql, postgresql

**I have the following example table:**

| User | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2016-01-01 |
| A | 2017-01-01 |
| A | 2018-01-01 |
| A | 2019-01-01 |
| B | 2017-03-05 |
| B | 2017-11-01 |

**I am trying to achieve the following:**

1. Take the minimum (first) date for each user
2. Count all subsequent records for each user in a 2 year timeframe AFTER the user's minimum date

**Below is an example of what I want to achieve using PostgreSQL:**

| User | min_date | count_of_records_in_following_8_months |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2016-07-01 | 2 |
| B | 2017-03-05 | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a window function to get the minimum date.  Then aggregate:

```
select user,
       count(*) filter (where date > min_date and date < min_date + interval '8 month')
from (select t.*, min(date) over (partition by user) as min_date
      from t
     ) t
group by user;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2ee490a2accdcf64be3b9a7fac484538) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  `user` is a reserved word so it should not be used as a column name.

Comment: Gordon -- here is the error I get with this: **"SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 23 unexpected '('. "**

Comment: Gordon -- what do you mean? It is not the real name of that column but i've adjusted for that. The error is on LINE 2. It looks like the "FILTER" syntax is not suitable using Snowflake...

Comment: @Hyder . . . If you have a question about Snowflake, then ask a *new* question with an appropriate tag.  This question is clearly about Postgres and has a Postgres-compliant answer, along with a db<>fiddle.